# how can i separate okhttp3 class in activity to another class

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, okhttp

i created okhttp3 method in activity and works well, but then i want call this okhttp3 method from another activity, so i believe i need to separate this okhttp3 by creating separate class, so i need help how to create separate okhttp3 class

this is method that i create in activity

```
public void getJsonData(final int method, final String email, final String password, final String page, final String token){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request;
        RequestBody formBody;
        HttpUrl gurl;
        //mToken = token;
        if(networkIsAvailable()){
            if(method == POST){
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url = "http://35.240.138.251/api/auth/login";
                formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("email", email)
                        .add("password", password)
                        .build();
                request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();
            } else {
                 gurl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                        .scheme("http")
                        .host("35.240.138.251")
                        .addPathSegment("api")
                        .addPathSegment(page)
                        .addQueryParameter("token",token)
                        .build();
                request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(gurl)
                        .build();
            }
            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    if(method == POST){
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gangguan koneksi, periksa koneksi internet anda!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               SHOULD WE MOVE THIS --> errorAlert(); <--

                              -->  login(); <--
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String intoken = mJsonManager.getToken();
                                if(!nager.isEmpty()) {
                                    getJsonData(GET,null,null,"wartarutin",intoken);
                                } else {
                                    getJsonData(GET,null,null,"wartaprofil",intoken);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if(response.code() == 401){
                        if(method == POST) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                  -->  reLoginAlert(); <--
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    getJsonData(POST,email,password,null,null);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        if(method == POST) {
                            try {
                                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                                mJsonManager.setToken(jsonData);
                                Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        -- > loginArea.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); <--
                                        String inToken = mJsonManager.getToken();
                                        mToken = inToken;
                                        if (nager == null) {
                                            getJsonData(GET, null, null, "wartaprofil", inToken);
                                        } else {
                                            getJsonData(GET, null, null, "wartarutin", inToken);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            String jsonData = response.body().string();
                            switch(page){
                                case "wartaprofil":
                                    try {
                                        mJsonManager.setProfilStat(PrologueActivity.this, jsonData);
                                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                              -->  openTitle();  <--
                                            }
                                        });

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "wartarutin":
                                    try {
                                        mJsonManager.setWartaStat(PrologueActivity.this, jsonData);
                                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                goToMainApp();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

so json data is pass to JsonManager class and save by this class to database.
i want to call this method from another activity so i dont have to repeat the same method in another activity.. please share your ideas..

Answer (score 1):

1. Your can create a BaseActivity and then all activities extends it,
2. move your method to BaseActivity,
3. you can invoke it in any Activity which extends BaseActivity.

follow is your BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{ 
    //here is your method body
    public String methodA(Runnable run){
        //handle your result in run
        runOnUiThread(run);
        return "hello-world";
    }
}
```

follow is your ActivityA

```
public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //invoke methodA
        String myData = methodA(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //handle json data
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: how do we do that??

Comment: I reedit my post,please check it,got any question please let me know.

Comment: if you see in each okhttp response result i call method to runOnUI thread.. how do we resolve that to base activity??

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do,could you describe more details?

Comment: ok.. i have moved method `getJsonData()` to `BaseActivity` do i have to moved other method which is called inside `getJsonData()` to `BaseActivity` as well.. if so.. how about the component like `ProgressBar`  how do we resolve that.. i will put mark in my question..

Comment: No,just move getJsonData() to BaseActivity and invoke getJsonData() in ActivityA,ActviityB,ActivityC and so on.

Comment: For handling your result ,you can add a params Runnable run for getJsonData(),then it will looks like getJsonData(Runnable run);after get json data you can handle it in Runnable which will be initialized in ActivityA,ActivityB and so on.I reedit my answer,check it.

Comment: how about params that i use in `getJsonData(String email,String password)`

Comment: add three params getJsonData(String email,String password,Runnable run)

Comment: i am confused.. and still stuck.. the result is available in base activity but can not invoke in activityA..

Comment: what's the error ?could you post your current code in your question?